# Will my hardware support Windows 10 1809?

Tags: windows-10

I am currently running Windows 10 Pro 1803 onmy PC having the following specs:

- Processor - intel Core 2 Duo E7500 2.93 GHz 3 MB L3 Cache
- Motherboard - HCL Pegatron IPM41
- RAM - 2 GB DRR2
- Screen Resolution - 1440x900
- Storage - 250 GB Hard Drive

Actually I wish to upgrade to Windows 10 Pro 1809 x64. But since I am not able to gather much support for my hardware, I doubt whether I will be able to do that even when I am meeting all the minimum specifications. Please help.

Comment: Yes, your hardware is enough, it can support Windows 10 1809. It has meet the Windows 10 1809 system requirements. You can refer to this link which is regard to the requirements of Windows 10 1809: https://wccftech.com/windows-10-1809-system-requirements/

Answer (score -1):

If you are currently running Windows 10 x64 and have enough hard disk space, then the upgrade should work with your hardware (but might take a long time).

Upgrading from Windows 10 x86 (32-bit) to x64 (64-bit) will require a clean install. 64-bit drivers for older printer may be unavailable, but other than that, I have seen many Core 2 Duo systems running Windows 10 x64 (with occasional lag).

With only 2GB RAM (upgrading to 4GB is recommended), if using integrated graphics on the motherboard, you may need to minimize the shared video memory setting in the BIOS (if available).

Generally speaking, nearly all PCs from 2008 or newer (yours is from 2009) should be able to upgrade, as well as many that are older than that. For example, I have a dual Intel Xeon 2.8 PC (~2007 currently on Windows 7 x64) that will run Windows 8.0, but not 8.1 or higher, due to lack of support for certain required CPU instructions that were not present in all of Intel CPUs until 2008.

Comment: Thanks. I am running Windows 10 Pro 1803 x64 right now.